# Prove or disprove if a series is convergent that it implies the square of the series is convergent as well

Tags: sequences-and-series

Heyy,

Can we prove or disprove the following

$$
\Sigma a_n \text{ is convergent} \Rightarrow \Sigma a_n^2 \text{ is convergent}
$$

Since the statement cannot be proven without knowing whether the series is positive, is there a proper counter example

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

$$a_n:=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$$

Comment: I posted the comment before your edit ;) But now we have two duplicate answers...

Comment: according to wolframalpha this series is divergent

Comment: @Man  Then either you mistyped the series or else WA is high...again. The series is convergent, of course.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli No, I think you're confusing things...

Comment: @Timbuc can u suggest me a test to check if this is convergent?

Comment: @Timbuc I probably misread the question, then.

Comment: @ManZzup Google "Leibniz series" or Leibniz test.

Comment: @Timbuc but alternating test is true only of a_n is convergent isnt it? which is in this case 1/(sqrt(n))

Comment: @ManZzup No. It **must be** more than simply convergent: the positive  sequence $\;a_n\;$ must converge **monotonically** to zero.

Comment: @Timbuc ahh got it thankxx :)

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Consider $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$.